# Recently viewed widget display nothing - Magento 2.0.8

Tags: magento2, admin, cms, widgets

I installed Magento 2.0.8 without sample data.

When I insert the widget in the static block, it does not show any recently viewed product in home page(after sign in).

why it is not work in cms static block, below content is generated when I insert the widget in the block.

```
{{widget type="Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed" page_size="5" template="widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml"}}
```

But when I do from **content->widget** and assign to cms home page main content it worked but it is always displayed on top of the **content container** even setting sort order 2000.

**Note:** I have tried with the below three configurations but no luck

```
store->configuration->catalog->recently viewed/compared->store
store->configuration->catalog->recently viewed/compared->website
store->configuration->catalog->recently viewed/compared->storeview
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

while you using this code

> {{widget type="Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed" page_size="5" template="widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml"}}

or insert widget in static block with code you should in Cache Management page disable FPC then reload home page (ctrl + f5).

[image]

Comment: it worked. can you look this doc http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html they recommends to enable FPC. I worked with 2.0.1 with sample data it worked with enable FPC :-)

Comment: This way is an incorrect way but it work temporary ;-)